# How to use wp_trim_words and read more?

Tags: wordpress

I need to use the `wp_trim_words()` function, along with a "read more" text that when clicked shows the rest of the content just underneath, like a toggle.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [How to add Read More to Wordpress](https://www.wikihow.com/Add-Read-More-to-Wordpress)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add your current code to your question

Comment: Davy M, yes! but applied to wp_trim_words() function.

Comment: cmaher

echo wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 40, '...' );

I need a "read more" button that when clicked displays the rest of the content..

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 40, '...');
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 40, 'Read More');
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 40, 'See More');
?>
```

For tuggle you need to use javascript or jquery. When you will use jquery/script, no need to use wp_trim_words function just use some text with ancher tag(control) and hide/show some content on click.

Comment: do you know a way to have different wp_trim_words(.....) word length based on the browser resolutions?

Answer (score 0):

To display page content you might be using the_content() or echo get_the_content(). But instead you just use below line

```
echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), $string_length, $text_read_more_optional); //example, $string_length=50, $text_read_more_optinal='Read More'
```

So, i guess your code would look something like this:

```
if(have_posts()){
    while(have_posts()){
        the_post();
        the_title(); //display title
        echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 100, 'Read More'); //display content
    }
}
```